# Update DynamoDB table to reflect new schema through CloudFormation without deleting entire stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I modified my CloudFormation template to have different hash and sort keys on one of my DynamoDB tables.

When I try to re-deploy the stack I get `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` and upon inspection I see error:

`Error: CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename 'MYResourceXXX' and update the stack again`.

This seems to be because I have an existing table with the same name but different schema.

How should I proceed to get CloudFormation to recreate the table with the same name but different schema?

- I don't need to backup the data on this table
- I could delete the table (manually or otherwise)
- I CANT delete other infrastructure

Using a test account, I tried going into the console and manually deleting the table and then re-deploying the CloudFormation template but it doesn't re-create the new table even though I deleted it and the stack deployment completes successfully.

The stack on this test account was not in the state `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE`, not sure if that matters.

Also, when I check the stack for drift, it correctly detects the table has been deleted but not sure how to fix that or if I should even be deleting it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford to lose the original table and its data, the best solution would be:

- Rename the table in your cloudformation stack
- Update the stack. Cloudformation will delete the old table and create a new one. There would be no drift.

If you absolutely need to have the same name. Go through the above process once more.

In the code below, rename both the resource name (MyDynamoDBTable) and the actual table name (DynamoDBTableName). You will probably also need to modify your policies that grant access to the table.

```
MyDynamoDBTable:
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
Properties:
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: 'KeyId'
      AttributeType: 'S'
  KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: 'KeyId'
      KeyType: 'HASH'
  ProvisionedThroughput:
    ReadCapacityUnits: '5'
    WriteCapacityUnits: '5'
  TableName: !Ref DynamoDBTableName
```